# How to document errno value with Doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a function that set `errno` when error occurred. I want to document the possible `errno` values. But it seem like Doxygen only supports exception, not `errno`. Is it possible to document `errno` values like [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen doesn't appear to explicitly support documenting `errno` values. Consequently, I would  use Doxygen's markdown capability to create an indented table:

```
/**
 * ...
 * Errno values:
 * ~~~
 * Value  | Meaning
 * ------ | ----------------
 * EINVAL | Invalid argument
 * ~~~
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually set errno when something wrong happened, so as a workaround you can use the "exception" section to document errno values like this:

```
/**
 * function description
 * \returns 0 if everything's okay
 * \returns -1 if something went wrong and set `errno` accordingly. See exceptions below.
 * \exception EINVAL wrong parameter was provided
 */
```